# Running sudo command from Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

Is there a way to let a tomcat 7 server (running on an Ubuntu Server) execute a sudo command in a command line?
In this specific case I want to make it possible to shut down the system from another server.
What code would I have to use?
And do I have to run the tomcat server as root or can i get these privileges at runtime and only for this action? 
Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea, but if your tomcat process is being run by a sudoer, you can use a ```java.lang.Process``` to run any commands that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to run Tomcat as root, you can just add tomcat user to `/etc/sudoers` to allow him run superuser commands, like `sudo shutdown now`. This way allows you to specify desired subset of commands that can be executed by user. E.g. to allow him to run only `shutdown`:

```
tomcat ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

To run shell commands from Java code you can call one of [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) or use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

P.S. Also try googling about `/etc/shutdown.allow` file which allows running shutdown command by any user that is listed in it. But I've never used it.