# Running a sudo command in a Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, permissions, sudo

I saw this question answered:

[Running sudo command from Tomcat servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854759/running-sudo-command-from-tomcat-servlet)

So I setup the sudoers file with:

```
tomcat ALL=NOPASSWD: <script name>
```

and in the servlet, i have

```
try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
     } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

where command is:

```
sudo <script name>
```

When the servlet runs, I get the error:

```
Cannot run program "sudo": error=13, Permission denied
```

Is there a permissions or a configuration I need to change in Tomcat?  This is running on Centos 7 and Tomcat 7.

Thank you

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: Elliot Frish: thank you for the suggestion, but i tried that already, and i still get the same error.

Comment: `tomcat ALL=NOPASSWD: <script name>` == recipe for being hacked.

Comment: The error message is telling you that whatever user Tomcat is running as does not have the necessary authority to execute the `sudo` command itself.  This has nothing to do with the contents of `sudoers`, it hasn't gotten that far yet.  If you have selinux enabled there's probably a rule preventing this.

Comment: Jim Garrison:  This is for a proof of concept only.

Comment: "Proof of concept" usually means it will end up in production somewhere if the project is green-lighted.

Comment: Jim Garrison:  It was selinux that was blocking.  thank you very much.